# Style aside, is there any reason to prefer simple `CASE WHEN` to searched?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I wish to write the following

```sql
CASE [FOO]
WHEN 1 THEN 'YES'
WHEN 0 THEN 'NO'
WHEN NULL THEN 'NO'
END
```

I could, of course, write

```sql
CASE
WHEN [FOO] = 1 THEN 'YES'
WHEN [FOO] = 0 OR FOO IS NULL THEN 'NO'
END
```

instead.

Style aside, is there any reason (e.g. performance) to prefer one over the other?

Comment: `WHEN NULL` isn't doing to work, equality against a `NULL` returns UNKNOWN, which isn't TRUE. Though if `Foo` is a `bit` you could just do `CASE Foo WHEN 1 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END`

Comment: @ThomA Well, that's a damn good answer. "You should write the second because the first doesn't even work" completely solves my problem.

Comment: There is no performance difference though, the less/more verbose method would work the same "under the hood".

Comment: You could also write case foo when 1 then 'yes' else 'no' end. But it might be not what you want, if for example when foo is 3 your code returns null, while this code returns 'no'

Comment: ...or even shorter (assuming, of course, `foo` is indeed a `bit` )- `IIF(foo = 1, 'YES', 'NO')`.  As documented - "IIF is a shorthand way for writing a CASE expression. "

Comment: [the parser always expands CASE expressions to the nested form](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/42850/3690)

Comment: The first form can only deal with non-null equality. The second form can deal with all cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no performance reason.

You might expect that

```
SELECT CASE ( scalar_subquery )
         WHEN 0 THEN '0'
         WHEN 1 THEN '1'
         WHEN 2 THEN '2'
       END
```

might have an advantage and only evaluate the subquery once as it only appears in the text once. But this is not the case.

[image]

There is a good semantic reason for you to use the "Searched" syntax here though. The "Simple" `CASE` expression is just a short hand way of testing for equality (`=`) - Not [`IS`](https://www.sql.kiwi/2011/06/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.html#the-answer).

So unless you are running with `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF` (and you shouldn't be!) then this won't work as you desire.

If you look at the execution plan for the first statement you see it gets expanded out to nested "Searched" expressions anyway (and optimises out the redundant branch when `ANSI_NULLS` is `ON`)

```
  CASE
     WHEN [FOO] = ( 1 ) THEN 'YES'
     ELSE
       CASE
         WHEN [FOO] = ( 0 ) THEN 'NO'
         ELSE NULL
       END
   END
```

when `ANSI_NULLS` is `OFF` it appears in the plan as

```
  CASE
     WHEN [FOO] = ( 1 ) THEN 'YES'
     ELSE
       CASE
         WHEN [FOO] = ( 0 ) THEN 'NO'
         ELSE
           CASE
             WHEN [FOO] IS NULL THEN 'NO'
             ELSE NULL
           END
       END
   END
```

Your second one appears in the plan as

```
  CASE
     WHEN [FOO] = ( 1 ) THEN 'YES'
     ELSE
       CASE
         WHEN [FOO] = ( 0 ) OR [FOO] IS NULL THEN 'NO'
         ELSE NULL
       END
   END
```

Even when you do just have strict `=` requirements so either would work the "nested" expansion can occasionally [cause problems with linked servers](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42837/why-do-linked-servers-have-a-limitation-of-10-branches-in-a-case-expression/42850#42850) so when you have multiple cases leading to the same `result_expression` combining these in the same `Boolean_expression` with `OR` (using "Searched" form) can be beneficial in reducing the level of nesting.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the 1st style when possible and you have a good value to CASE on.

The 2nd syntax is more flexible and can take a wide array of values, so you are sometimes forced to use that syntax.